# Im trying to create a currency spinner in JQuery UI, but its not working, what do I need to do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im trying to create a currency spinner in JQuery UI, but its not working, what do I need to do?

```
   $( "#spinner" ).spinner({ min: 0, numberFormat: "C" });
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Any javascript errors?  Add your html too please.

Comment: you need to read through the API to find out where you have made a mistake. http://jqueryui.com/spinner/ http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/

Comment: no errors, but my expected output is $2.00 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same problem but found a solution (which I'm still implementing).

You need to specify the *culture* of the currency you want to see. Which involves downloading some extra stuff...

Go to: https://github.com/jquery/globalize
and download the project, you'll need to reference *the Globalize.js* file and include the culture you want. Your system can't rightly show a monetary amount without knowing where in the world it's from, right?

I'll be back to update this post when my code is up and running. Hope that helped at least a little!

Comment: You don't necessarily need to download anything to work this out. (well at least not until run time)